# Sending error from separate file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a signup page and am currently working on the verification of input (checking if they're empty, etc).

I'm handling the PHP in a separate file (the action file) when the form is submitted:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="username" class="span-default" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

What I need to do is add the following code under the input tag shown above if an error is found:

```
<div class="form-warning">ERROR TEXT HERE</div>
```

This is a portion of my PHP code. How would I do what I specified above from a separate file (or is there a better way)?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username)) {
  // action here
}
```

Please help.

Comment: That doesn't help much. :/

Comment: What does it mean `That doesn't help much.`? AJAX is the only way.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I know almost nothing about AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is *not* the only way. There are multiple solutions where javascript is not necessary at all. I've posted one as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the error message in `$_SESSION` and check for the existence in your form page.

form.php:

```
if (isset ($_SESSION['error']))
{
   echo '<div class="form-warning">' . $_SESSION['error'] . '</div>';
}
// The rest of the form here

unset ($_SESSION['error']); // Necessary so the error won't be reused/redisplayed unless it is later set again in submit.php
```

submit.php:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username))
{
   $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error message here';
}
```